# Weird margin probelem in Chrome

Tags: margin

I've problem with margin in my Chrome (21.0.1180.79 m) . However the problem doesn't exist in Firefox 14.0.1.

Here's the screeshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y57Tl.jpg (sorry I can't attached image since I'm new and are not allowed to attach an image)

In chrome, when I add top margin to the Menu 2, it will overlapping with the Menu 1. In other words, the margin of the Menu 2 starts at the bottom of Menu 1.

I use

margin: 50 auto 20px;

Works fine in Firefix, but not in Chrome. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

That's called [margin collapse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/margin_collapsing)

You can fix it, for example, adding floating: http://jsfiddle.net/bRJgB/1/ and http://jsfiddle.net/bRJgB/1/show/.

You can also fix it adding a separator between them (an empty element with `overflow` different than `visible`, or with `border` or `padding`).